# how to iterate through map of custom object in lightning

Tags: apex, lightning

I am trying to fetch Map in my lightning js controller.

Apex Controller:

```
 @AuraEnabled
public static Map<CustomObject__c, custObj__c> getQuestions(){
    Map<CustomObject__c,custObj__c> quesOpMap = new Map<CustomObject__c, custObj__c>();
    List<custObj__c> obj = [SELECT Id,Name FROM custObj__c];
    for(CustomObject__c q : [SELECT Id,Name FROM CustomObject__c] )
    {
        for(custObj__c opt : obj){
                   quesOpMap.put(q, opt);
            }
    }
    return quesOpMap;
}
```

JS Controller:

```
 var action = component.get("c.getQuestions");
    // Add callback behavior for when response is received
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
       var state = response.getState();
       if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            component.set("v.questions", response.getReturnValue());
        }
        else {
            console.log("Failed with states: " + state);
        }
```

on loading app I am getting error as 'Unable to parse JSON Response' and if check console log for `response.getReturnValue()`. this is undefined.

But If I replace `Map<CustomObject__c, custObj__c>` with any primitive type for e.g. - `Map<Id,String> or Map<String,String>`, js controller is working fine.

How to get values for custom objects in lightning controller?

Comment: The Apex code posted in the question is not correct as you are trying to put a string in the map against the key, whereas you have defined map of objects

Comment: Can you please check your debug logs

Comment: @maniaccoder I mistaklenly posted the wrong code. Edited it correctly

Answer (score 2):

Your Map cannot be serialized to JSON, as the return values of `@AuraEnabled` controller methods are, because it uses an object as a key.

It's fine to return a map of a primitive to an object, like `Map<String, CustomObject__c>`, but you can't use a custom object as the Map key in this context.

Comment: so its not possible to set Map key as custom object?

Comment: @AnkurGupta Right. Keys must be Id or String. Coincidentally, it would make sense to just write something like `quesOnMap.put(q.Id, opt)`.